# What's a process for determining table links?

Tags: oracle

I need to make several queries to get information out of our Oracle 12c database. I've used oracle SQL Developer to determine primary and foreign key relationships, but how do I link tables when there are no foreign-primary keys defined?

I've thought of using helper tables in creating links, but again, I don't know what helper tables to pick.

Comment: Why can't you type the 'JOIN` statement yourself?

Comment: Are you looking for ways to write SQL joins, or looking for ways to identify table relationships through the data dictionary, as in reverse engineering the data model?

Comment: I am looking for ways to find table relationships that don't exist in the data dictionary.

Comment: If the developers didn't see fit to create the foreign key relationships than the best you can do is guess. This often happens when developers use an Object Relational Model (ORM) that instantiates the database objects for them. The ORM keeps track of the relationships in the Java code. Unfortunately, most applications built in the last 15-20 years are like that.